# How to copy database from ec3 instance mongodb to local machine

Tags: mongodb

I formatted my machine and all the data in mongodb deleted. I want to copy all the data from my server machine to local db.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the following steps to backup your mongodb instance on EC2 and restore it to your local mongodb instance.

Assumptions: A non-sharded deployment and authentication is enabled

1. Backup mongodb running on EC2:

> `mongodump --host mongodb1.example.net --port 27017 --username user --password "pass" --out /opt/backup/mongodump-2011-10-24`

2. Compress the output data file

> `tar -cvzf mongodump-2011-10-24.tar.gz /opt/backup/mongodump-2011-10-24`

3. Copy compressed DB dump from EC2 to you local machine using `scp` and `pem file`
4. Restore uncompressed dump to local mongodb instance:

> `mongorestore --port 27017 mongodump-2011-10-24`

5. Verify DB stats on local machine

> `mongo>  use yourDB`

> `mongo>  db.stats()`

Answer (score 0):

Using mongoexport, first take a backup of mongodb on instance. Then copy the file using steps below.

- To copy files between your computer and your instance you can use an
  FTP service like FileZilla or the command scp which stands for secure
  copy.
- To use scp with a key pair use the following command: scp -i
  path/to/key file/to/copy
  user@ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:path/to/file.
- To use it without a key pair, just omit the flag -i and type in the
  password of the user when prompted.

Answer (score 0):

1. Dump your db on some folder in server

   > `$ mongodump -d db-name -o folder-name-to-dump`
2. Copy server db to your local machine using scp command.

   > `$ scp -i xyz_aws_ec2.pem  aws-amazonaws.com:path/to/db/*  path/to/some/folder`
3. Restore DB to your local machine after successfully copied the db.

   > `mongorestore -d db-Name path/to/some/folder`

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use s3cms on ec2 , you have to install it

wget -O- -q http://s3tools.org/repo/deb-all/stable/s3tools.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo wget -O/etc/apt/sources.list.d/s3tools.list http://s3tools.org/repo/deb-all/stable/s3tools.list
sudo apt-get install s3cmd

then configure
s3cmd --configure

then backup script

    #!/bin/bash

#Force file syncronization and lock writes
mongo admin --eval "printjson(db.fsyncLock())"

MONGODUMP_PATH="/usr/bin/mongodump"
MONGO_DATABASE="dbname_here" #replace with your database name

TIMESTAMP=`date +%F-%H%M`
S3_BUCKET_NAME="bucketname_here" #replace with your bucket name on Amazon S3
S3_BUCKET_PATH="mongodb-backups"

# Create backup
$MONGODUMP_PATH -d $MONGO_DATABASE

# Add timestamp to backup
mv dump mongodb-$HOSTNAME-$TIMESTAMP
tar cf mongodb-$HOSTNAME-$TIMESTAMP.tar mongodb-$HOSTNAME-$TIMESTAMP

# Upload to S3
s3cmd put mongodb-$HOSTNAME-$TIMESTAMP.tar s3://$S3_BUCKET_NAME/$S3_BUCKET_PATH/mongodb-$HOSTNAME-$TIMESTAMP.tar

#Unlock database writes
mongo admin --eval "printjson(db.fsyncUnlock())"
#Delete local files
rm -rf mongodb-*
```